# O que preciso saber para trabalhar com backend em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, back-end

Quais são as principais tecnologias, ferramentas, enfim, o que é necessário para trabalhar com backend usando C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se tratando de tecnologias/ferramentas, aprender a usar:

- LINQ
- Entity Framework
- Fundamentos de SQL
- GIT
- Protocolo HTTP/HTTPS
- Injeção de dependência
- Testes de unidade / serviço
- Mapeamento de objetos
- Framework de Log
- Princípios SOLID
- Design Patterns

Para aprender não precisa ser especialista no assunto, é apenas não ser algo desconhecido para você.

Answer (score 3):

Desenvolvi um projeto para a faculdade utilizando C#, Visual Studio, ASP.NET Framework e arquitetura MVC.

No começo não sabia nada, porém as ferramentas são sensacionais.
A própria IDE do Visual Studio permite criar um modelo de projeto baseado no ASP.NET que é um Framework para aplicações WEB, que fornece inúmeros recursos e uma facilidade imensa em se trabalhar.

Utilizei o banco de dados do SQL Server, que já vem integrado ao Visual Studio e com a utilização do recurso "migrations" que permite versionar o controle do banco, onde caso ocorra um erro em alguma modificação em tabela, você possa voltar a uma versão anterior.

Além disso é possível gerar as classes na arquitetura MVC com o entity framework, basta criar suas entidades.

Resumindo: 
Visual Studio - na minha opinião melhor IDE.
ASP.NET - Framework para desenvolvimento de aplicações web.
Banco de dados - de sua escolha, SQL Server e migrations facilitam a utilização com o Visual Studio.
Arquitetura MVC - bastante utilizada atualmente.
Entity Framerwork - mapeamento de relações.

Com isso consegui desenvolver um projeto sem saber praticamente nada, apenas com alguns tutoriais.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, primeiro você obviamente precisa aprender a linguagem c#. Se você está começando, estude .net core, e depois estude LINQ e expressões lambda, com eles você consegue criar uma aplicação web muito boas sem escrever um único código SQL.

E claro estude o padrão MVC.